# modelbinding on ASP.NET MVC Razor engine failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The model binding just isn't working for me - I always get NULL coming through to the controller! Any thoughts people?

Rob

Here is my action signature:

```
public ActionResult SearchForUser(SearchForUserModel m)
```

Here is my Razor header model declaration:

> @model WebOne.Models.StatusIndexModel

StatusIndexModel is a composite model containing SearchForUserModel:

```
public class SearchForUserModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Search information required")]
    [DisplayName("Contact Search")]
    public string Search { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Razor:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchForUser", "Status")) 
    {
    <div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchForUserModel.Search)
                <input type="submit" class="formbutton_small" value="Find" />
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.searchForUserModel.Search)
            </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<form action="/Status/SearchForUser" method="post">        
    <div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Search information required" id="searchForUserModel_Search" name="searchForUserModel.Search" type="text" value="" />
            <input type="submit" class="formbutton_small" value="Find" />
            <br />
             <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="searchForUserModel.Search" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the prefix:

```
public ActionResult SearchForUser(
    [Bind(Prefix="searchForUserModel")]SearchForUserModel m
)
```

Comment: Ahhh - is that because I'm creating a variable and not using the class definition? That wasn't necessary in plain-old-asp.net-MVC... - but you're right and thank you!  I need to wait another 8 minutes to accept your answer because you were so quick!

Comment: @Rob, that's because your post action accepts a `SearchForUserModel` whereas your view is strongly typed to `StatusIndexModel` and the generated field name is `searchForUserModel.Search`, so the model binder looks for a `searchForUserModel` property inside `SearchForUserModel` and it doesn't find one. When you specify the prefix you indicate to the model binder that the root should start after this prefix.

Comment: Ah I got it, thanks again Darin. Is this the most appropriate way to handle multiple forms on a Razor powered controller or is there a better way?